# Read file line by line and perform action for each in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file, it contains a single word on each line.

I need a loop in bash to read each line, then perform a command each time it reads a line, using the input from that line as part of the command.

I am just not sure of the proper syntax to do this in bash.  If anyone can help, it would be great.  I need to use the line from the test file obtained as a paramter to call another function.  The loop should stop when there are no more lines in the text file.

Psuedo code:

```
Read testfile.txt.
For each in testfile.txt
{
some_function linefromtestfile
}
```

Answer (score 10):

How about:

```
while read line
do
   echo $line
   // or some_function "$line"
done < testfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, using a file descriptor (#4 in this case):

```
file='testfile.txt'
exec 4<$file

while read -r -u4 t ; do
    echo "$t"
done
```

Don't use `cat`! In a loop `cat` is almost always wrong, i.e.

```
cat testfile.txt | while read -r line
do
   # do something with "$line" here
done
```

and people might start to throw an [UUoCA](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) at you.

Comment: No need to use a different file descriptor unless you know there is a conflict with other commands reading from standard input.

Comment: @chepner - exactly, that was why I added the answer above; beny23 gave a perfect answer and I added an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line
do
   nikto -Tuning x 1 6 -h $line -Format html -o NiktoSubdomainScans.html
done < testfile.txt
```

Tried this to automate nikto scan of list of domains after changing from cat approach. Still just read the first line and ignored everything else.